# How to simulate key presses when another key is pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity, input

I have an activity where I want to add a handler to the main activity's onKeyDown method and in that method, simulate another keypress. The method is being called, but for some reason the simulated keypress is not working when using the activity's dispatchKeyEvent method, or when just trying to call the onKeyDown method again like so `return this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER));`. How can I reliably (and easily if possible) simulate a keypress?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `View` on which you want to simulate the key press **and** this `View` has an `OnClickListener` set - you can use the method `performClick()` on that `View` to activate its `OnClickListener`.

Example with a `TextView`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.myTextView );
tv.setOnClickListener( new MyOnClickListener() );
tv.performClick();
```